# Data modeling - strategy game - over-normalization?

Tags: database, database-design

I am trying to build a travian-like web browser game (static strategy game). I am currently working on my tables and data model. I don't have much experience with relational databases and I am wondering if I am not doing to much normalization.

So in this game, everything is about resources, there are 4 different types of resources: `wood`, `clay`, `iron` and `corn`. They are needed to feed your army and workers; it is also used as a resource for building buildings and upgrading fields.

I currently have +25 PSQL tables, split between **master** (static) tables and **transactions** tables. When I started, I did not have a table to assign IDs to my 4 types of resources. The name of each resources was in the column. One example:

**building_upgrades_cost:**

```sql
    CREATE TABLE
      master.building_upgrades_cost (
        id serial NOT NULL,
        building_type_id INT NOT NULL,
        level INT NOT NULL,
        duration INT NOT NULL,
        cost_wood INT NOT NULL,
        cost_clay INT NOT NULL,
        cost_iron INT NOT NULL,
        cost_corn INT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        FOREIGN KEY (building_type_id) REFERENCES master.building_types(id)
    );
```

So if I wanted to check what what the total cost to upgrade **building_id** `4` at **level** `13`, the query was simple:

```sql
    SELECT 
      * 
    FROM
      building_upgrades_cost as costs
    LEFT JOIN master.building_types as building_type ON costs.building_type_id = building_type.id
    WHERE cost.building_type_id = 4 costs.level = 17
```

**result, return a single row:**

| building_id | level | duration | cost_wood | cost_clay | cost_iron | cost_corn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 17 | 60 | 500 | 600 | 650 | 350 |

What I changed and why:

I did not think it was a good option to have my 4 resources in form of columns. Like:

- What about if I am adding a new resource to the game?
- Not have the same 4 columns over and over in most of the tables (resources are required for everything)
- In may increase difficulty to perform some queries without a proper id assigned to each resource

So I decided to create a new table called `master.resources_types`:

```sql
    CREATE TABLE
      master.resources_types (
        id serial NOT NULL,
        resource VARCHAR(15),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
    INSERT INTO
      master.resources_types
        (resource)
      VALUES 
        ('wood'),
        ('clay'),
        ('iron'),
        ('corn')
    ;
```

Now, this new design add some complexity to the previous data model. I built an extra table to store the amount of resource required by type of resource for each type of building for each level. Let's say we have 10 different buildings, 20 levels max, so the number of rows in this table is: number of buildings * max levels * number of type of resources = 10 * 20 * 4 = 800.

The **update query** is a bit more more with a new LEFT JOIN. The updated query **return now 4 rows** because each resource required to make the upgrade was its own line:

| building_id | level | duration | resource_id | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 17 | 60 | 1 (wood) | 500 |
| 4 | 17 | 60 | 2 (iron) | 600 |
| 4 | 17 | 60 | 3 (clay) | 650 |
| 4 | 17 | 60 | 4 (corn) | 350 |

Do you think making this extra resource table was a good choice?

Comment: "Do you think making this extra ressource table was a good choice?" : yes.

Comment: if you want further advice, I would say "avoid starting with a database. start with code, then  make a database to persist data"

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, this is my project: https://github.com/Pierre-Alexandre35/travian.

Comment: i had a quick browse and i would say yes, you have started with the database and the front end, rather i would start with a console app version of the game all in memory. its your turn, do you : upgrade village, fight, pass? implement the logic first then add a pretty front end and gamestate persistence to a database

Comment: I disagree with @Ewan and think that a database-first approach is entirely valid.

Comment: @Ewan thank you for having a look. I am actually trying to clone travian.com, so there will be a lot of things to do, yeah its a persistant browser game. The thing I will have to figure out is the best way to update user ressources, upgrades, troops movements. It can't be updated every 1 second, I think i will have a currenttimestamp and previousstimestamp and calculate the diff. A table to register all the current events that are in construction / progress

Comment: @pjc50 in your opinion, are both options seems legit?

Comment: I'd argue that you should start with a logical data model and then worry about persisting it.

Comment: I would expect that the total costs for a given building are based on rules.  That is, the costs only depend only on the type of the building and other game state.  I'm not sure I understand your goals with this last table.  What is the goal behind assigning these values on a per-building basis?